# How to use ceiling here?

Tags: sql, oracle

when i run this code shows an error CEILING:invalid identifier please help me to find the ceiling of Diff_In_Secs here..

```
 select a.action, CEILING(avg(extract(minute from b.RECEIVED_TS - a.RECEIVED_TS)*60
    + extract(second from b.RECEIVED_TS - a.RECEIVED_TS))) Diff_In_Secs
    from request a, reply b where a.ID = b.ID 
and a.RECEIVED_TS > trunc(sysdate) - 10
and b.TARGET_ID is not null
group by a.ACTION
order by diff_in_secs desc;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "how to apply"?  What happens when you try to run the query above?

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
select a.action, CEILING(CEILING(avg(extract(minute from b.RECEIVED_TS - a.RECEIVED_TS)*60
    + extract(second from b.RECEIVED_TS - a.RECEIVED_TS)))) Diff_In_Secs
```

Answer (score 0):

Old question but I ran into the same problem... in my case it didn't like CEILING; use CEIL instead to make it work.