# ORA-00904: "CEILING": invalid identifier in ORACLE 11G

Tags: oracle11g

ceiling in oracle 11g throws java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "CEILING": invalid identifier.
Till now are used Oracle 10G, now we upgraded to 11G,afterthe we are getting ""CEILING": invalid identifier" error

can any one help on this please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [please help me to use ceiling here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377772/please-help-me-to-use-ceiling-here)

Answer (score 2):

There is no function `CEILING` that is part of any stock Oracle database install of any version.

If you are using a function `CEILING` in your 10g database, that implies that it is a user-defined function.  If that function doesn't exist in 11g, you'd need to create it there.

Oracle does have a function `CEIL` that takes a number and rounds up to the next highest integer.  If that's all you are doing, it probably makes more sense to use the built-in function rather than writing your own wrapper function.