# ORA-00904: "CEILING": invalid identifier

Tags: oracle11g

Using `CEILING` function in `oracle 11g` throws `java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "CEILING": invalid identifier`. Using `CEIL` function works fine. `CEILING` function is not available in any oracle version, please confirm.

Comment: You've already asked this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19318487/ora-00904-ceiling-invalid-identifier-in-oracle-11g 50mins ago?

Comment: If you didn't believe Justin for some reason, you should have asked for clarification on that question, not opened a new one. The available functions are well documented [for 11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions.htm#i1482196) and [for 10g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions001.htm). `Ceiling` does not exist; if you used to have it then it was a user-defined function, not a built in, as Justin said. It would be highly unusual for functionality to be removed anyway as it would break old applications.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.2.2/ref/rreffuncceil.html), where they give you samples of `CEIL` and `CEILING` usage in JDBC but not in Oracle, where we use `CEIL`